# save array to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have array in swift like this one

```
["002012295915", "00971595502", "8885555512", "5555648583", "4085555270", "0562825196", "01147220964"]
```

what is the best way to save into mysql database using php code

Comment: `json_encode()` and then store to the database like text. When your ready to use it again, do `json_decode()`

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay but if you allow iam very week in this area  do you have any example for that

Comment: It's literally one of the easiest things you can do. `json_encode($array)` and store that to the database, and to use it later `json_decode($arrFromDB,true)`

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Dear Grumpy thank you for your help it was helpful to me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're planning on saving all of the array as one string in the database you can just use `mysqli_query`, and `mysqli_real_escape_string`:

Saving all of the array as one string:

```
$arr = ["002012295915", "00971595502", "8885555512", "5555648583", "4085555270", "0562825196", "01147220964"];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","db");
mysqli_query($con,"insert into TABLE values('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$arr)."')");
```

And if you want to print it later just use the `select from TABLE where`.

Saving each value by itself (without regex knowledge):

```
    //LET'S MAKE THE ARRAY MORE BEAUTIFUL FOR THE LOOP WITHOUT REGEX.

    $arr = str_replace('[','',$arr); 
    $arr = str_replace(']','',$arr);
    $arr = str_replace('"','',$arr);

//NOW THE ARRAY LOOKS LIKE THAT: 002012295915, 00971595502, 8885555512, 5555648583, 4085555270, 0562825196, 01147220964
//WE JUST NEED TO SPLIT IT NOW


$new_Array = explode(',',$arr); //DEVIDE ARRAY ELEMENT BY ','

//OK NOW WE JUST NEED TO PUT EACH ONE AS A SINGULAR VALUE IN THE DATABASE.

 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","db");

foreach($new_Array as $data)
{
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES('$data')");

}
```

Comment: Thank you this almost work for me great thanks

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help :)